# Spark Streaming - Create RDD based on delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working with a Spark and have a stream of messages flowing which are seperated by a message-start delimiter,

I would like to create a seperate RDD for each message ie. each time we see the delimiter character.

Is this possible in Spark Streaming?

**Edit:**

```
 class RouteConsumer extends Actor with ActorHelper with Consumer {
   def endpointUri = "rabbitmq://host:5672/xchange?queue=hl7"
   def receive = {
     case msg: CamelMessage =>
       val m = msg.withBodyAs[String]
       store(m.body)
   }
}

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(3))   

val dstream = ssc.actorStream[String](Props(new RouteConsumer()), "SparkReceiverActor")

val dStreamSplit = dstream.flatMap(_.split("MSH|^~\\&"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes. How is the initial `RDD` doing your data ingestion represented ?

Comment: Thanks, I am having difficulty in understanding how to achieve this. I've added a code snippet as to where I am.